# What is the exact equivalent of fftpack/ezfftf.f (which performs a Fourier analysis on a real periodic sequence) in scipy.fftpack?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

The fortran library fftpack has a function ezfftf.f which computes the Fourier coefficients of a real periodic sequence (Fourier analysis). EZFFTF is a simplified but slower version of RFFTF (https://github.com/eliteraspberries/udsp/blob/master/fftpack/ezfftf.f). I am wondering if there is an equivalent routine in scipy/fftpack that does this. I have tried scipy.fftpack.fft to compare with the fortran ezfft.f routine, but the Fourier coefficients are way off for the same test data.

Comment: Please be more detailed and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do I understand correctly—EZFFTF is slower than RFFTF (which Scipy does provide), yet you want to use EZFFTF? Just out of personal curiosity, can you explain why?

Comment: That's right! I am trying to translate some old legacy Fortran codes to reproduce the exact results in python. No joy yet!

Comment: @user278423 did you resolve this? I am working on the same exact issue

Comment: @AhmedFasih unfortunately the results from ezfftf do not equal the scipy/numpy fft versions which I suspect is why the user asked the question (and same reason why I am working on this now)